# json array not being posted to PHP using Javascript post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

In the view:

```
function updateData(that){


    f = new test();

for (var i = 0; i < dataContext.length; i++)
{
    f.test.push(new Person(dataContext[i].test, dataContext[i].test1, dataContext[i].Line1, dataContext[i].Id));

}

        $.post("<?php echo $base_url;?>index.php/controller/function/<?php echo $details['Id'];?>", { data: JSON.stringify(f) }, function (res) {
    });
}
```

Now within the php function, function:

```
function () {
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

returns an empty array.

The data is basically within a javascript wizard. It seems like when I click "finish", the page does not refresh itself. $_POST is only called when the page first loads.

I am quite new to javascript and not sure what I am doing wrong, cheers.

Comment: `f` is never defined.

Comment: amended it, see above

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.stringify(that)` in place of `JSON.stringify(f)` like,

```
function updateData(that){
    var url="<?php echo $base_url;?>index.php/controller/function/<?php echo $details['Id'];?>";
    $.post(url, { data: JSON.stringify(that) },function (res) {
        alert(res);
    });
}
```

**Updated** if `f` is defined then try it like,

```
function updateData(that){
    var url="<?php echo $base_url;?>index.php/controller/function/<?php echo $details['Id'];?>";
    $.post(url, { data: JSON.stringify(f) },function (res) {
        alert(res);
    });
}
```

Give `some name` to your `php function` or call form jquery like,

```
// call updateData function in your controller
var url="<?php echo $base_url;?>index.php/controller/updateData/<?php echo $details['Id'];?>";
```

**Create** a function `updateData` in your `controller` like,

```
function updateData($id=''){
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: "f" is the array that I want to pass into the the JSON object